# How to combine Top App Bar and Drawer?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-design, jsx, web-component

I am trying to place [Top App Bar](https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/) beside [Drawer](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/drawer) like [Drawer and Top App Bar](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/drawer/permanent) demo and it looks not as expected:

[image]

The code looks like(I am using react):

```
<div className="content">
  <aside className="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--permanent mdc-typography">
    <nav className="mdc-drawer__drawer">
      <header className="mdc-drawer__header">
        <div className="mdc-drawer__header-content">
        {ReasonReact.string("Header")}
        </div>
      </header>
      <nav id="icon-with-text-demo" className="mdc-drawer__content mdc-list">
        <a className="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#">
          <i className="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" ariaHidden=true>{ReasonReact.string("inbox")}</i>{ReasonReact.string("Inbox")}
        </a>
        <a className="mdc-list-item" href="#">
          <i className="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" ariaHidden=true>{ReasonReact.string("star")}</i>{ReasonReact.string("Star")}
        </a>
      </nav>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <div className="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--fixed">
    <div className="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
      <section className="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
        <a href="#" className="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon">{ReasonReact.string("menu")}</a>
        <span className="mdc-top-app-bar__title">{ReasonReact.string("Title")}</span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style of the class `content`:

```
@import "~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
@import "~@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar.scss";
@import "~@material/drawer/mdc-drawer.scss";

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and further style:

```
@import "./App/scss/app.scss";

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The root is the entry point of react.

The question is, what do I have to do to get the desired result.

Comment: With [antd](https://ant.design/components/layout/) this can be achieved quite easily.

Comment: @zero_coding did you figure it out ? it looks like the drawer is not ready yet for the toolbar replacement...